# x86 ASM handling of eax with * operator

Tags: assembly, operators, ida

How to interpret `*` operation in assembly? Does it involve some kind of an array operation?

Example snippet from IDA, involve the use of program arguments:

```
mov     eax, [ebp+arg_0]
mov     ecx, [ebp+arg_4]
mov     edx, [ecx+eax*4-4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a multiplication.

In x86 you can access memory using the following expression in a single instruction.

```
*(base + offset*multiplier + displacement)
```

Where base and offset are registers, multiplier is 1, 2, 4 or 8 and displacement is a constant.

Usually when you see this you're looking at an array operation, for example `ecx - 4` (which is just `arg_4 - 4`, where `arg_4` is a pointer) is likely to be the start of an array of 4 byte integers and `eax` (which is just `arg_1`, where `arg_1` is a `size_t`) would be the offset into the array. It can, however, be absolutely anything. When programs are compiled with optimizations the compiler will use these constructs to pull all sorts of clever tricks.

Comment: Thanks. Considering it is an array operation how can I determine what exactly is happening with it utilizing the operator (static analysis only)?

Comment: It's almost certainly doing this: void f(int *arg_0, int arg_4) { int edx = arg_0[arg_4 - 1]; ...}